# Best Practice when Declaring and Initializing variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

As I am just starting with c++, I am trying to keep my code clean, readable and correct.

I have a question as to what is the best practice when declaring and initializing variables.

In Programming principles and practice in c++ by Bjarne Stroustrup, he advised to always initialize your variables if you can. That I understand.

What wasn't mentioned was the correctness of declaring variables in a single line statement like this:

```
  int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0;
```

as against using three different statements like this:

```
  int value1 = 0; 

  int value2 = 0;

  int value3 = 0;
```

Of course the second way is more readable and probably manageable, but the first is kind of a quick way, which I suppose is not advised? 
Which is best practice and why? Does it affect compilation in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: The second one is clearer, and avoids some problems like `int* value1 = 0, value2 = 0;` where you (accidentally) might declare one pointer and one `int`.

Comment: The case for always initializing variables is more complex than it might seem at first. Essentially it avoids warning noise from the compiler about possible use of an uninitialized variable, which is a warning that you do want to have for the situation where initialization was intended but forgotten. Then better to initialize also where it's not technically needed: the cost at run-time is usually miniscule.

Comment: You could also declare them as `int v1, v2, v3;` assuming you are not giving a value to them at that point. If you were initialize new variables with  different values I would use the second one as it is more legible. Also important to keep in mind who might be using/reading your code later on.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. I haven't gotten to the use of pointers yet, but I have read a lot on it. I will stick to the second one. Neil Butterworth already mentioned there is no effect on compilation speed or emitted code.

Comment: Don't just blindly initialize all your variables to 0. What's so special about 0? It's better to declare your variables at the point where they are first used: then, you will have a real value to initialize them with.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, true. Like I mentioned, he said when you can.

Comment: Something I didn't see mentioned yet in terms of best practice is the practice of AAA - or Almost Always Auto. This is something recommended by C++ luminaries like Scott Meyers (item 5 of his book Effective Modern C++), Herb Sutter (see [GotW #94 Solution: AAA Style](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)), and Bjarne Stroustrup (see the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-auto)). In my own words though, I love how `auto` works for C++ and suggest it be considered for a "Best Practice".

Comment: @LouisLangholtz I think that has to do with type safety?

Comment: @Onome Agreed. `auto` can help with type safety. And it can also help with initialization too as `auto` variables have to be initialized (preventing a coder from forgetting to initialize them).

Comment: Good information. I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of compilation speed, there is no difference between the 2 methods; the difference lies more in the styling of the code. Having said that, declaring multiple variables of the same data type is more prone to errors if the variables are pointers. I'll go over the 2 methods below:

---

#### Method 1 is more prone to errors in some situations

When you declare variables of the same data type in a single line, like the example you provided: `int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0;`, this is more prone to errors. For example, if you wanted to do declare 3 pointer variables of type int, then the following:

```
int* value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0;
```

would not be the right way to declare them, as it would mean that the first variable is a pointer, but the second and third ones are non-pointers of type int; the above line could be rewritten as:

```
int* value1 = 0;
int value2 = 0;
int value3 = 0;
```

Which is not what we want; we want to do this:

```
int* value1 = 0;
int* value2 = 0;
int* value3 = 0;
```

Therefore, in this case, the variables in separate lines as declaring them in the same line will not have the intended effect.

NOTE: If you really want to declare them in the same line, then you can do the following:

```
int* value1 = 0; int* value2 = 0; int* value3 = 0;
```

This would solve the problem of pointer declaration and only differ from separate lines by style of code.

#### Method 2 is more pleasing to read (this is opinion-based)

Another thing is that the second method of declaring your variables in separate lines improves the readability of the code. Note here that this is opinion-based; some people that are more used to reading them on the same line, and in that case, method 1 is better for them.

---

So to conclude, after you are sure that declaring the variables on the same line will not affect the meaning of your code (sorry for poor choice of words here) like it *did* in the example in the first header, then it boils down to the style of the code you prefer. As for execution time, it really makes no difference.

Comment: This is very clear and well detailed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When I started to learn code it helped me to separate variable upon declaration. It helped me keep the variables organized by having them on separate lines. There is no execution difference in the way these two lines are coded. However, as you rise through the programming ranks your instructors will probably advise this format.

```
  int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0;
```

Once you start working on large projects it helps to keep sections of your code as compact as possible. In this declaration having 1 line vs 3 keeps more tidy code. If you were doing this declaration hundred of times, 1 versus 3 lines of code can really add up.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: "as you rise through the programming ranks your instructors will probably advise this [the comma separated] format.". Fire your instructors.

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine, and there is no real effect on compilation speed, or emitted code. The big question would be why you would need three integer variables in a function in  the first place. You want to keep your functions as short as possible (but no shorter), which means you often won't have three or more variables.

Comment: Thanks. I can relate to the need of the optimum length of a function. But what about functions that prompt the user for input. How do you get around using less than three variables?

Comment: You'll find that real programs don't prompt users for input using the standard C++ input mechanisms. And if they do, you can, and probably should, write one function to get each single input.

Comment: It makes sense. It only becomes so obvious after someone mentions it.